# How to include php variable in script src

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a variable that holds url to access css and js files. Now I successfully created in config and including it in header for `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/css/style.css" />` and it just works fine.

But how do I include the same way in the script tag placed in the footer?

In my config.php

```
 $path = "http://localhost/mysite/";

    <script>
     var path = "<?php echo $path;?>";
    </script>
```

In header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/css/style.css">
 <script src="<?php echo $path; ?>/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>//this works, doesn't leave any error.
```

But in footer:

`<script src="<?php echo $path; ?>/js/jquery.myplugin.js"></script>`//same style I used in header. But doesn't work!

If pressed f12 in chrome, under sources js files that placed in the footer not loaded but the one placed in header yes!

Comment: What `$path` is containing?

Comment: "Doesn't work" — what do you mean? Maybe `$path` variable was redefined somewhere before footer?

Comment: @b0s3, $path = "http://localhost/mysite/";

Comment: Are you sure that your header and footer are both **PHP** files?

Comment: @umka, redifined? how?, I defined in config and included the config in header

Comment: If you see the source code of the page, the $path content in the footer is empty?

Comment: @Turtle, yes they are

Comment: Remove `/` at the end. Change `$path = "http://localhost/mysite/";` to `$path = "http://localhost/mysite";`

Comment: `http://localhost/mysite//js/vendor/modernizr.js` There's one extra / here. Besides, don't use absolute paths. Just load `js/vendor/modernizr.js`. The absolute path will become invalid as soon as you put your site on another server than your Localhost.

Comment: Check the source for what it is printing in the `src`

Comment: @umka, I think you're right!..It gets redefined as I used it inside script tag in config. I removed the script and now it works

Comment: You have a scope issue. Move the `<script>` stuff from config to header, and include config in BOTH header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove this part form config

```
<script>
     var path = "<?php echo $path;?>";
    </script>
```

I define it twice

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable like `define('SITE_PATH','http://localhost/mysite/');` in your config file. Use `<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>` where ever required.